# Tomcat8 shutdown memory error with OpenJDK.1.8.0_131

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, memory

I am trying to deploy an web application with Tomcat8. When I shutdown tomcat instance following message show up in console.

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00000005c0000000, 6442450944, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 6442450944 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/my/path/project/apache-tomcat-8.0.28/bin/hs_err_pid7710.log
The stop command failed. Attempting to signal the process to stop through OS signal.
Tomcat stopped.
```

So when I open the file, I could find below statement.

```
---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )

Other Threads:

=>0x00007f9e6000a000 (exited) JavaThread "Unknown thread" [_thread_in_vm, id=7711, stack(0x00007f9e69    497000,0x00007f9e69598000)]

VM state:not at safepoint (not fully initialized)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread:  ([mutex/lock_event])
[0x00007f9e60007f30] Heap_lock - owner thread: 0x00007f9e6000a000

GC Heap History (0 events):
No events

Deoptimization events (0 events):
No events

Internal exceptions (0 events):
No events

Events (0 events):
No events
```

What `VM state: not at safe point` means? 
Here is my command to executed java.

```
VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Xms6144m -Xmx8192m -XX:MetaspaceSize=256m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m -XX:+UseG1GC -Djava.awt.h    eadless=true -verbose:gc -Xloggc:/home/my/path/project/apache-tomcat-8.0.28/logs/gc.log -Djava    .library.path=/home/my/path/project/lib -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/home/my/path/project/apache-tomcat-8.0.28/endorsed -Dcatalina.base=/home/my/path/project/apache-tomcat-8.0.28 -Dcatalina.home=/home/my/path/project/apache-tomcat-8.0.28 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/my/path/project/apache-tomcat-8.0.28/temp
java_command: org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap stop
java_class_path (initial): /home/my/path/project/apache-tomcat-8.0.28/bin/bootstrap.jar:/home/my/path/project/apache-tomcat-8.0.28/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD
```

I looks that does not effect to the web service. Is it OK to ignore?

How can I handle this error properly?

FYI,

- tomcat : `8.0.28`
- jdk : `OpenJDK.1.8.0_131`
- OS : `GNU/Linux x86_64`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running out of virtual memory on your system. You need to post the memory configuration of your system. With these options you should at least have 10 GB of physical memory. Also the JVM options of the stop script, and the output of

```
free -m
```

With your current options

```
-Xmx8192m -XX:MetaspaceSize=256m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m
```

Means Tomcat alone is going to use more than 8960 MB of virtual memory (you'll have to add code cache, stacks and native memory). The stop script also needs additional memory (hopefully you have different JVM options for this) an so do the other processes on your machine. Swapping a JVM is not a good idea because the garbage collector regularly runs over the entire heap.

> What VM state: not at safe point means (sic)?

They specific points in the execution of a Java program when the state of the execution is known the the VM. I recommend [Safepoints: Meaning, Side Effects and Overheads](http://psy-lob-saw.blogspot.ch/2015/12/safepoints.html) for details.